# RobotFramework: Getting "TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks"

Tags: python, robotframework

I am getting the "TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks" error while trying to use the `isinstance()` function only when using through RobotFramework.

Please let me know whether I am doing something wrong.

Created the following directory structure,

```
|
|- lib/
|  |- mylib.py
|- tests/
   |- mytest.robot
```

Here is the content of `mylib.py`

```
from typing import Union, List

class mylib:
  @staticmethod
  def fun(x: Union[str, List[str]]):
    if isinstance(x, str):
      x = [x]
    print(x)
```

Content of `mytest.robot`

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ../lib/mylib.py

*** Test Cases ***
My Test
    ${y}=    Create List    abc    xyz
    mylib.fun    x=${y}
```

Here is the run output,

```
D:\tmp\robot>python -m robot --loglevel DEBUG tests
==============================================================================
Tests
==============================================================================
Tests.Mytest
==============================================================================
My Test                                                               | FAIL |
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests.Mytest                                                          | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Tests                                                                 | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  D:\tmp\robot\output.xml
Log:     D:\tmp\robot\log.html
Report:  D:\tmp\robot\report.html
```

The log.html is showing the below error,
[image]

If I run the same code through Python interpreter (using Python 3.8.5), it works!

```
>>> from typing import Union, List
>>>
>>> class mylib:
...   @staticmethod
...   def fun(x: Union[str, List[str]]):
...     if isinstance(x, str):
...       x = [x]
...     print(x)
...
>>> mylib.fun('abc')
['abc']
>>> mylib.fun(['abc', 'xyz'])
['abc', 'xyz']
>>>
```

Using the below RobotFramework version.

```
C:\Users\amit_tendulkar>python -m robot --version
Robot Framework 4.0.1 (Python 3.8.5 on win32)
```

What might be going wrong in RobotFramework?

**UPDATE:** If I change the function definition to below (`List` instead of `List[str]`), the test starts passing,

```
class mylib:
  @staticmethod
  def fun(x: Union[str, List]):
    if isinstance(x, str):
      x = [x]
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was with older version of RobotFramework (4.0.1).

I upgraded my RobotFramework to 4.2 and the above test case started working without any issues.

```
PS D:\personal\robot_experiment> py -m robot --version 
Robot Framework 4.1.2 (Python 3.8.10 on win32)
```